# Do I need to transfer the manufacturer's warranty to the buyer when selling a second-hand laptop?

Tags: united-kingdom, used-goods

I intend to sell a second-hand gaming laptop on Gumtree soon; it'll be my first time selling an item online, so I've done all the research I could to prepare for this.

At first, I was convinced that I didn't need a bill of sale for an item as small as a laptop; but then I realized I'd need one if I intend to transfer the remaining manufacturer's warranty to the buyer (I'd really rather not have to do this since it's too much hassle).

Am I legally bound to transfer the remaining manufacturer's warranty to the buyer?; or can I just list in the description of the laptop "-Warranty not included" and be rid of all the extra hassle? (I live in the UK if that's of any relevance :D)

Comment: Yes you can just say "warranty not included" and this is OT

Comment: Unfortunately, most electronic warranty is not transferrable if it already registered under your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on the terms of the warranty.  Some are not transferable at all.  Some require that the new owner registers the warranty.  Some just require proof of purchase, such as the receipt.

Warranties are in addition to statuary rights, not instead of them.  Nobody is obliged to offer a warranty.  You have no obligation to transfer the warranty to the new buyer, but it may put off buyers if you say you aren't going to do so.